# Cannot connect to bitcoin-qt server

Tags: bitcoin-core

```
 # server=1 tells Bitcoin-QT to accept JSON-RPC commands.
 server=1

 # You must set rpcuser and rpcpassword to secure the JSON-RPC api
 rpcuser=bhhtufhrt
 rpcpassword=ferhrhh
```

im trying to connect to my bitcoin thats my conf file but i cant connect to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8832/
```

im running on my local machine

Answer (score 1):

The default port I think should be 8332 not 8832, however if you modify your config file to include:

RPCPort=8832

Then restart server and it should work

Answer (score -1):

You may want to add the following line to your .config file:

```
listen=1
```

Comment: mmm, interesting, I thought that -server implied listen as well? Does anyone know for certain on this?